# Write Excel Formula in VBA Coding Error "1004"

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting Excel VBA Error "1004" on executing the following formula..

[Click to see the Excel Formula Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3TRS.png)

..in VBA Code

```
For i = 5 To lastrow
      ws2.Cells(i, lastcolumn + 1).Formula = "=DATEVALUE(INDIRECT(LEFT($F$1,1)" & i & "))+TIMEVALUE(INDIRECT(LEFT($H$1,1)" & i & "))"
      ws2.Cells(i, lastcolumn + 1).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Next i
```

Does anyone know how to make sure to write the VBA Code correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If `i` was 1 your formula resolves to

```
=DATEVALUE(INDIRECT(LEFT($F$1,1)1)) + +TIMEVALUE(INDIRECT(LEFT($H$1,1)1))
```

You are missing the `&` in the formula.

```
For i = 5 To lastrow
      ws2.Cells(i, lastcolumn + 1).Formula = "=DATEVALUE(INDIRECT(LEFT($F$1,1) & " & i & "))+TIMEVALUE(INDIRECT(LEFT($H$1,1) & " & i & "))"
      ws2.Cells(i, lastcolumn + 1).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the formula cell in **N5**, then
run this code:

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

Take a look at the immediate window and fix your formula correspondingly.